Как получить результат потоков в том порядке, в котором они запустились?
Всех приветствую.
Немного (много) запутался в многопоточности.
Задача написать программу, которая скачает картинки с сайта.
Код следующий (некоторые места типа импортов убрал для упрощения понимания):
# Программа, которая параллельно скачивает картинки флагов

# Очередь из ссылок на картинки флагов 
flag_url_queue = Queue()
# Заполняем ссылками. Кусок кода с парсингом ссылок убрал
for link in all_flag_link[:5]:
    flag_url_queue.put(link)

# Главная очередь, которая должна в правильном порядке сохранять файлы 
# и выводить текст об успешном скачивании картинки
main_queue = Queue()


def download_flag(url_img):
    # Кусок срезаной строки использую для сохранения по имени и вывода в консоль
    print(f'Начал скачивать {url_img[-10:]}')
    result = requests.get(url_img)
    print(f'Скачал {url_img[-10:]}')
    return result, f'{url_img[-6:]}'


def save_flag(img_b, url_img):
    print(f'Сохраняю флаг {url_img[-6:]}')
    with open(f'./images/{url_img[-6:]}', 'wb') as img_file:
        img_file.write(img_b.content)
    print(f'Сохранил флаг {url_img[-6:]}')


def worker(flag_url_queue: Queue, main_queue: Queue):
    while not flag_url_queue.empty():
        try:
            #  Пытаюсь достать ссылку без блокировки потока
            new_link_flag = flag_url_queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            break
        else:
            #  В главную очередь попадает результат функции - 
            #  ответ requests и имя картинки 
            main_queue.put(download_flag(new_link_flag))
            # Помечаю задачу как выполненную 
            flag_url_queue.task_done()


def main():
    COUNT_THREAD = 4
    thread_list = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(flag_url_queue, main_queue)) for _ in range(COUNT_THREAD)]

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()

    flag_url_queue.join()

    for item in thread_list:
        item.join()

    while not main_queue.empty():
        save_flag(*main_queue.get())

Я ожидаю, что картинки, возможно, будут скачиваться в разноброс, но в результате сохранятся в той последовательности, в которой они запустились.
Допустим, есть флаги Австралии (au.png), Австрии (at.png) и Азербайджана (az.png).
При запуске получаю
Начал скачивать h80/au.png
Начал скачивать h80/at.png
Начал скачивать h80/az.png

Скачал h80/at.png  <----- Скачались в другом порядке
Скачал h80/az.png
Скачал h80/au.png

Сохраняю флаг at.png <--- Начинают сохраняться в том порядке, в котором скачались, а не в изначальном
Сохранил флаг at.png

Сохранил флаг az.png
Сохранил флаг az.png

Сохраняю флаг au.png
Сохранил флаг au.png

Я жду, что они начнут скачиваться в изначальном порядке. Т.к. каждая из них весит по-разному, то я допускаю, что они загрузятся в другом порядке. Но я бы хотел, чтобы в результате они сохранялись в первоначальной очерёдности (Австралия - Австрия - Азербайджан).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать такое с помощью threading?
Вопрос больше для того, чтобы разобраться в теме. Проект пишется "на скорую руку" и не претендует на практическое применение.
Заранее спасибо.

Если в очередь закидывать ещё и индекс, а потом его учитывать при сохранении картинок, то думаю желаемого эффекта можно добиться. Вопрос только один, а зачем?)

@Amgarak в последнем абзаце написано зачем) Идея с индексами хорошая, и наверное единственно верная

Вторая очередь не нужна. Заведите вместо неё глобальный список нужного размера, заполняйте его по индексам. Синхронизация этому списку не нужна.
